# Minimum value of |z| for the locus of a complex number z

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have a question that involves an Argand diagram. The complex number **u = 1 + 1i** is the center of that circle, and the radius is one. In other words, $$|z - (1 + 1i)| = 1$$

Now my issue is the following: I need to **calculate the least value of |z| for the points on this locus using the diagram**. Here's the sketch:

[image]

So how do I find that least |z|? I understand that it'll involve a tangent to the circle, and I assume it's on the bottom right side of the circle, closest to the origin, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: What point on a circle is nearest to a given point outside the circle?

Comment: You can solve this using geometry (not tangents but normal)...OR you can use Lagrange multipliers (which is not [pre-calculus])

Comment: We know $\lvert z\vert$ is the distance from $0$. What point is closest to the origin? Can you infer what its argument is and go from there?

Comment: Why do you write $1+1i$ instead of simply writing $1+i$?

Comment: @José I think the beginner might find it easier to calculate things when they see the 1. Eventually it comes naturally, I remember being pretty slow with it, and seeing a 1 before $i$ would help quicken my thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest point is the point on the line through the origin and $(1 + i)$.

The distance between the origin and the centre is $|1+i| = \sqrt{2}$

The distance between the centre and the point is 1 (radius is 1)

So the distance we want is $\sqrt2 - 1$.

From a visual standpoint, it should be clear why this is the closest point. However we can make this rigorous by noting for any $z$ on the circle:
4

$$ 1 = |z - (i+1)| = |(i+1) - z| \geq |i+1| - |z| $$

$$ |z| \geq |i+1| - 1 = \sqrt{2} - 1$$

So at the shortest we can get is $\sqrt2 - 1$, which we've shown is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Join a line from the origin to the center of the circle, once that is done ... label each term geometrically.

Note: $|z|$ is distance of the point $ z$ from the origin